# Collapsing activity post comments in BuddyPress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

How do I modify the "comments" section to allow collapsing of comments? If comments get too long, they just keep growing on the page and not allow for a collapsing. Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried anything ?